# How can i get UID by email address on firebase auth for react native app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native

I want to develop a app that has a feature to add friends. I am taking email address of that friend which he/she want to add from user. Then I want to add that friends UID to users UID. So I need a way to find UID of user by his mail address. Is there any way to do this on firebase database for react native app?[image: firebase database auth]

Comment: You may look at the documentation which explain how to programatically create users. For web: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#create_a_user and for Android https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Answer (score 0):

The firebase Admin SDK provides API to lookup users by uid, email and phone numbers: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data